# Fingerprint matching

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics, interfacing

I'm building a payroll system and would like to use fingerprint scanner to control time attendance.

I was wondering how it would interface with java web app. Is there a way to get the log in real-time (when the user swipe the finger and matched) through network connection?

I know there are software that comes with scanners that can do the time attendance but I want to keep the log in our database and manage the data.  All I need the device to do is match the finger print and send the log (id,date,time…)

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this twice. One device was tethered via USB to a PC, and I hired someone to study the API and write a Visual Basic app to POST the data to a website, where PHP+MySQL accepted and stored the entry. Another device worked over Ethernet, and was more complex to integrate. It totally depends on the manufacturer, their API, and the means of communication.

If I were to do this again, I'd look first into an Arduino-type device such as https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11651